# Form submit success in every browser except Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I've been working on this form for a bit, and it seemed like I solved every error I had earlier and the contact form works. The problem is it works in every browser except Firefox, and I guess it's because the security level in ff is higher. We work with a high-security level, and my first guess was that Content-Security-Policy was blocking it, but when I don't validate before submitting it works fine.

This is the code I have, note the last script in HTML, normally an include from include_recaptcha.html

```js
const form  = document.getElementById('kontaktskjema');
    const email = document.getElementById('mail');
    const emailError = document.querySelector('#mail + span.errorkontakt');
    const navn = document.getElementById('navn');
    const navnError = document.querySelector('#navn + span.errorkontakt');
    const telefon = document.getElementById('telefon');
    const telefonError = document.querySelector('#telefon + span.errorkontakt')
    const message = document.getElementById('message');
    const messageError = document.querySelector('#message + span.errorkontakt')
    const navnboks = document.querySelector('.navnboks')
    const teleboks = document.querySelector('.teleboks')
    const mailboks = document.querySelector('.mailboks')
    const messageboks = document.querySelector('.messageboks')
    const vernboks = document.querySelector('.vernboks')
    const personvern = document.getElementById('checkbox');
    const personvernError = document.querySelector('#checkbox + span.errorkontakt')
    const submitbtn = document.getElementById('submitbtn');
   
    
    // THIS DIV WILL CONTAIN ERROR MESSAGES
    const errOutput = document.querySelector('.errorsOutput')


    email.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
      if (email.validity.valid) {
        mailboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-ok" )

        emailError.innerHTML = ''; 
        emailError.className = 'errorkontakt'; 
      } else {
        showError();
      }
    
    });


    navn.addEventListener('input', function (event) {

        if (navn.validity.valid) {
          navnError.innerHTML = '';
          navnError.className = 'errorkontakt';
          navnboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-ok" )

        } else {
            showError();
        }

    })

     telefon.addEventListener('input', function (event) {

        if (telefon.validity.valid) {
            telefonError.innerHTML = '';
            telefonError.className = 'errorkontakt';
            teleboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-ok" )

        } else {
            showError();
        }

    })

    
    message.addEventListener('input', function (event) {

        if (message.validity.valid) {
          messageboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-ok" )

            messageError.innerHTML = '';
            messageError.className = 'errorkontakt';

        } else {
            showError();
        }

    })

    personvern.addEventListener('change', function (event) {

      if (personvern.checked == true) {
        vernboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-ok" )

      } else {
          showError();
      }

  })




function makeRed() {
  if (!navn.validity.valid) {
    navnboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true")
  }

  if (!email.validity.valid) {
    mailboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true")
  }
  if (!telefon.validity.valid) {
    teleboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true")
  }
  if (!message.validity.valid) {
    messageboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true")
  }
  if (!personvern.checked == true) {
    vernboks.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true")
  }

};

function divFill() {
  if (navnError.textContent != '') {
    errOutput.innerHTML += '<li>Navn</li>'
  }
  if (emailError.textContent != '') {
    errOutput.innerHTML += '<li>E-mail</li>'
  }
  if (telefonError.textContent != '') {
    errOutput.innerHTML += '<li>Telefonnummer</li>'
  }
  if (messageError.textContent != '') {
    errOutput.innerHTML += '<li>Beskjed</li>'
  }

}

    function showError() {
    
      errOutput.innerHTML = ''
  

      if(navn.validity.valueMissing) {
        navnError.textContent = '* Du må fylle inn navnet ditt';
        navnError.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true" )
    } else if(navn.validity.tooShort) {
    navnError.textContent = '* Du må fylle inn hele navnet ditt'
    }
    

      
      if(email.validity.valueMissing) {
        emailError.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true" )
        emailError.textContent = '* Vennligst fyll inn e-posten din';
      } else if(email.validity.typeMismatch) {
 
        emailError.textContent = '* Dette er ikke en gyldig e-postadresse.';
      } else if(email.validity.tooShort) {

        emailError.textContent = `* Email should be at least ${ email.minLength } characters; you entered ${ email.value.length }.`;
      }


      
      if(telefon.validity.valueMissing) {
          telefonError.textContent = '* Du må fylle inn telefonnummeret ditt'
          telefonError.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true" )

      } else if(telefon.validity.tooShort) {
          telefonError.textContent = '* Du mangler ett eller flere tall. Vennligst dobbeltsjekk.'
      }

      
      if(message.validity.valueMissing) {
        messageError.setAttribute("class", "data-validation-error-true" )
        messageError.textContent = '* Beskjeden mangler, vennligst fyll inn'
      } else if(message.validity.tooShort) {
        messageError.textContent = `* Beskjed må være minst ${ message.minLength } tegn.`;
      }

   }
  
      

      emailError.className = 'errorkontakt kontaktactive';
      navnError.className = 'errorkontakt kontaktactive';
      telefonError.className = 'errorkontakt kontaktactive';
      messageError.className ='errorkontakt kontaktactive';
```

```html
        <div id="contact-form-wrapper" class="align-right-50 lazyload">
          <div id="contact-form-padding">
            <h2>Send oss en melding</h2>
            <p><span class="required">*</span> obligatorisk felt som du må fylle ut</p><br>
            
            <div class="errorsOutput">
            </div>
            <div class="skjema">
            <form id="kontaktskjema" action="nyhandler.kontakt.php" method="post"  novalidate>

              <input type="hidden" id="sendtfra" name="Sidetittel" value="{title}" />
              <input type="hidden" id="sendtfraURL" name="Side URL" value="{url}" />
              
              <div class="navnboks">  
                    <p>
                    <label for="navn">
                    <span>* Navn:</span>
                  <input type="text" id="navn" name="navn" required minlength="3" class="input-text w100">
                  <span class="errorkontakt" aria-live="polite"></span>
                </label>
              </p>    
            </div>
              
            <div class="mailboks">
                  <p>
                    <label for="mail">
                      <span>* E-post:</span>
                      <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail" required minlength="6" class="input-text w100">
                      <span class="errorkontakt" aria-live="polite"></span>
                    </label>
                  </p>
                </div>
              
                <div class="teleboks"> 
                      <p>
                        <label for="telefon">
                          <span>* Telefonnummer:</span>
                          <input type="tel" id="telefon" name="telefon" required minlength="8"  class="input-text w100">
                          <span class="errorkontakt" aria-live="polite"></span>
                        </label>
                      </p>
                    </div>
              
                    <div class="messageboks"> 
                          <p>
                            <label for="message">
                              <span>* Melding:</span>
                              <input type="text" id="message" name="message" required minlength="10" class="input-text w100">
                              <span class="errorkontakt" aria-live="polite"></span>
                            </label>
                          </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vernboks">
                            <input type="hidden" id="recapta" name="g-recaptcha-response" />
                            <p>
                              <label for="personvern">
                                <div class="personvern">
                                <span>* Personvern:</span>
                                <br>
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox" required>
                                <span>Jeg har lest og godkjent <a href="/ac/personvern">Personvernserklæringen (åpnes i nytt vindu)</a></span>
                                <span class="errorkontakt" aria-live="polite"></span>
                              </div>
                              </label>
                            </p>
                          </div>
              <button value="Send" class="button-send">Send</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render={sitekey}" async defer></script>
<script>
    var rcf = document.getElementsByName('g-recaptcha-response');
    for(var i=0; i<rcf.length; i++) {
        rcf[i].form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            if (!navn.validity.valid || !email.validity.valid || !telefon.validity.valid || !message.validity.valid) {
                makeRed();
                 divFill();
            e.preventDefault();
            } else {
            grecaptcha.execute('{sitekey}', {action: 'homepage'})
                .then(function(token) {
                    document.getElementById('recapta').value = token;
                    e.target.submit();
                });
    }});
    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e28pwzq7/

Comment: Any errors in the browser Console or anything like that? And have you traced it with the built-in JS debugger to see what the code is actually doing? There's a lot of code here and almost no debugging info. Also it's hard to see why this is tagged with PHP, it seems to be a purely client-side issue.

Comment: No errors, but warnings about Content Security Policy ignoring "unsafe-inline", "https: " and "http:" a bunch of times. Sorry about tagging PHP, thought it might be related to the handler, but seems like a longshot. If anyone wants to take a look at the live page, I can send a link.

Comment: That's not how Stackoverflow works. It's your job to do some basic debugging and post any and all info here (because, once your issue is fixed, your live link won't show the problem and therefore will be useless to future readers - they are just as much the audience for the answers as you are). So have you tried to trace this with the JS debugger in Firefox and see what happens?

Comment: Ah yes, ofcourse. My bad. I've been trying to JS debug, but I'm no expert. The token on the recaptcha (document.getElementById('recapta').value = token;) is undefined when I submit, but I do not have much experience with reCaptcha, so there's a chance it should be like that.

Comment: Well, since you're saying this is specific to Firefox, have you checked whether it's undefined at the same point in the code, when you run it in other browsers?

Comment: Also, you mentioned you get some security policy warnings...are they the same in other browsers too? Comparing and contrasting should help us to narrow down the issue.

Comment: It's undefined in chrome aswell, sadly. No security policy warnings in chrome dev tools.

Comment: Possibly then the security policy is causing something to fail to load which is essential for your code to run?

Comment: Yes, I think so. According to mdn web docs, Firefox is not supported for content security policy with external scripts. Currently working on finding a solution.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your continuous help. I solved it by adding a                 e.preventDefault(); in the second part of my function, after else.